# Why does member variable change, but object's address remains the same in this situation?

Tags: c++, constructor, this

In the following code I have an object of class `A`. I initiate its public member variable with the value of `0`. Then I call its method `ReplaceThis` which executes command `*this = A();`. Then I print the value and the address of the same object. The value is always some random gibberish while the address remains the same as before `ReplaceThis`. This confuses me, because unchanged address indicates that the object has not moved in the memory, nevertheless the value changes into some random data even though the constructor of `A` is empty.

If someone could explain what is going in this code step by step I would greatly appreciate it!

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    int Data;
    A() {}
    void ReplaceThis() { *this = A(); }
};

int main()
{
    A foo;
    foo.Data = 0;

    std::cout << "Initial  foo data: " << foo.Data << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Initial  foo address: " << &foo << std::endl;

    foo.ReplaceThis();

    std::cout << "Replaced foo data: " << foo.Data << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Replaced foo address: " << &foo << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Initial  foo data: 0
Initial  foo address: 0x7fff604594a0
Replaced foo data: 6296256
Replaced foo address: 0x7fff604594a0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We create the object:

```
A foo;
```

and set its `Data` member:

```
foo.Data = 0;
```

then, in `ReplaceThis()`:

```
*this = A();
```

means:

1. Create a new object (whose `Data` will be junk)
2. Assign that object's value(s) to our object
3. Nothing changed the address of our object
4. But we now have the new object's junk `Data`

Answer (score 1):

In this statement

```
*this = A();
```

there is called implicitly defined by the compiler the copy or move  assignment operator. It simply makes memberwise copy of the right hand object. Addresses of the objects are not changed.